# alternative to MVC that is loosely coupled?

Tags: php, model-view-controller, design-patterns

I work in a web shop as a PHP programmer.  Most of the time we use good coding practices but not much structure to the site as a whole.

I have now entered my phase of being bored with some of our practices and want to branch out and simplify and generate some things in a helpful way not just for me, but the hybrid-programmer web developers in the office.

One employee left us with a MVC site written in PHP, and I have had to maintain it a bit, and I get how it works but have my complaints, my main complaint is that it is tightly coupled with each piece dependent on another.  I see the advantage of the seperation of concerns, but this would be confusing to anyone but me looking at the code.

So for example, if I need to add a new page to the site, I have to go add a view, and then add a model, then update the controller.  The ad-hoc method of making a new page is way simpler than this and doesn't require a programmer.

My judgement was this was a much better method to build, rather then maintain, a website.

Still, it would be nice if I had some design patterns where I could reuse code effectively without it being dependent on a multiple places in the site.

So my question is, is there a design pattern for building and maintaining websites that is much more loosely-coupled?  I'm not looking for slight variations on MVC, I need something quite different to look at, maybe some type of plugin approach.

EDIT:

Thanks for the answers so far!  A different way of putting it is I want the code to be done better in my office.  Do I A) Push for MVC or B) find/build an alternative not as confusing to the half-programmers.  We already use classes for things like DB connectivity and Form helping.  The point of this question was to explore B.

Comment: Do you normally use some kind of templating language, as part of your "ad-hoc method"?

Comment: we use Smarty, but I don't like it.  I trip over smarty in the middle of form processing and would prefer to use the PHP IS the templating language approach.

Answer (score 3):

There's always a compromise between the code being confusing because it's highly deconstructionist, and the code being confusing because absolutely everything needed to do X is randomly scattered around a single file.

The problem with the latter is that exactly what is an "intuitive" way to split things up into monolithic modules differs between people. Highly decomposed and factored code is nearly always more difficult to wrap your head around, but once you do that, maintenance becomes both easy to do. I disagree that it would be confusing to anyone else but the author looking at it. Large-scope patterns like MVC are used because it becomes easier to spot them and work on projects structured around them over time.

Another advantage of using MVC is that you generally won't make the application more difficult to maintain for someone who comes after you if you don't stick to the layering. This is because now you have a predetermined place where to place any aspect of implementing a new feature.

As far as the tight coupling is considered, you can't really implement a feature without there being some connection between the layers. Loose coupling doesn't mean that the layers are ignorant of each other completely - it means that a layer should be unaware of how the other layers are implemented. E.g.: the controller layer doesn't care whether you're using a SQL database or just writing binary files to persist data at the data access layer, just that there is a data access layer that can get and store model objects for it. It also doesn't care about whether you use raw PHP or Smarty at the view layer, just that it should make some object available under some predetermined names for it. All the while the view layer doesn't even need to know there is a controller layer - only that it gets called with the data to display ready under the abovementioned names provided by /something/.

Answer (score 3):

As frameworks templates go, I find the MVC pattern to be one of the most "loosely coupled" ways of building an application.

Think of the relationships like interfaces, or contracts between the parts of the application. The Model promises to make this data available to the View and the Controller. No one cares exactly *how* the Model does that. It can read and write from a typical DBMS, like MySQL, from flat files, from external data sources like ActiveResource, as long as it fulfills its end of the deal.

The Controller promises to make certain data available to the View, and relies on the Model to fulfill its promises. The view doesn't care *how* the Controller does it.

The View assumes that the Models and the Controllers will keep their promises, and can then be developed in a vacuum. The Model and Controller don't care if the view is generating XML, XHTML, JSON, YAML, plaintext, etc. They are holding up their end of the contracts.

And, of course, the View and the Controller need to agree that certain things exist. A View without some corresponding Controller activity might work fine, but could never be used. Even if the Controller doesn't *do* anything, as might be the case in static pages:

```
<?php
class StaticController extends ApplicationController
{

    /**
     * Displays our "about" page.
     */
    public function about ()
    {
        $this->title = 'About Our Organization';
    }
}
```

Then the associated View can just contain static text. (Yes, I have implemented things like this before. It's nice to hand a static View to someone else and say "Just write on this.")

If you look at the relationships between the M, V, and C as contracts or interfaces, MVC suddenly looks very "loosely coupled." Be wary of the lure of stand-alone PHP files. Once you start including and requiring a half-dozen .inc files, or mixing your application logic with your display (usually HTML) you may have coupled the individual pages more loosely, but in the process made a mess of the important aspects.

```
<?php
/**
 * Display a user's profile
 */
require_once 'db.php';

$id = $db->real_escape_string($_GET['id']);
$user_res = $db->query("SELECT name,age FROM users WHERE id = $id;");
$user = $user_res->fetch_assoc();

include 'header.php';
?>
<h1><?php echo $user['name']; ?>'s Profile</h1>

<p><?php echo $user['name']; ?> is <?php echo $user['age']; ?> years old!</p>
<?php
include 'footer.php';
?>
```

Yeah, "profile.php" and "index.php" are completely unrelated, but at what cost?

**Edit:** In response to your edit: Push for MVC. You say you have "half-programmers," and I'm not sure which half (do you have front-end people who are good at HTML and CSS but not at server-side? writers with some programming experience?) but with an MVC framework, you can hand them just the views, and say "work on this part."

Answer (score 1):

I have to say that I don't really see your problem with MVC, since your already using templates anyway. I kind of think of it as the pattern that evolves naturally when you try to add structure to an application.

When people first start developing PHP application, the code is usually one big mess. Presentation logic is mixed with business logic which is mixed with database logic. The next step that people usually take is to start using some kind of templating approach. Whether this involves a specialized template language such as smarty or just separating out the presentation markup into a separate file isn't really important.

After this most of us discovers that it's a good idea to use dedicated functions or classes for the database access logic. This really doesn't have to be any more advanced than creating specialized functions for each commonly executed query and placing all those functions in a common include file.

This all seems very natural to me, and I don't believe that it's very controversial. But, at this point you're basicly already using an MVC approach. Everything beyond this is just more or less sophisticated attempts to eliminate the need to rewrite commonly used code.

I understand that this might not be what to you wanted to hear, but I think you should re-evaluate MVC. There's a countless number of implementations, and if it's really the case that none of them suits your needs, then you could always write your own and more basic implementation.

Look at it this way: Since you're already using a template language you'll typically need to create first a regular PHP file, and then a templare file each time you create a new page. MVC doesn't have to be any more advanced than this, and in many cases it isn't. It might even be that all you really need to do is to investigate more sophisticated approaches for handeling data access and add it to your current system.

Answer (score 0):

The fact that you have to create a new Model and Controller Action when you need a new page I don't think means that your M, V, and C layers are tightly coupled. This is just the separation of concerns and contributes to a decoupled system.

That said, it is quite possible to royally screw up the intent of MVC (and I've worked on an app like this) and make it make the components tightly coupled. For instance, a site might put the 'rendering engine' directly in the Controller layer. This would obviously add more coupling. Instead a good MVC will be designed so that the controller is only aware of the name of the view to use and then pass that name to the separate rendering engine.

Another example of bad design in an MVC is when the views have URLs hard-coded into them. This is the job of the Routing engine. The view should only be aware of the action that needs to be called and the parameter that action needs. The Routing engine will then provide the correct URL.

Answer (score 0):

Zend framework is very loosely coupled and is very good. Check it out:

http://framework.zend.com

This article might be of use too:

http://blog.fedecarg.com/2009/02/22/zend-framework-the-cost-of-flexibility-is-complexity/

Answer (score 0):

You can try code Igniter. Its very easy to learn and does not strictly adopt MVC whilst giving your code good structure.

Answer (score 0):

Code Igniter and Kohana (a CI descendent) are OK, but also loosely MVC.  I like the [simple php framework](http://clickontyler.com/simple-php-framework/).  It doesn't get in your way and it provides the important stuff, without forcing a structure or complicated conventions on you.

Answer (score 0):

Ah... good old MVC arguments.

I have to maintain a multi-faceted PHP application, pieces of which are written "MVC" style, but not all. Worse, different parts have different ways of doing MVC, all of which are homegrown. And some pages just do it all themselves.

The main problem is not that there is a diversity in framework code, but that the coders clearly did *not* understand how to abstract APIs. **IMO, ths is the biggest problem with MVC frameworks.** Almost all of the code I have to work with uses "models" as places to put functions. It is a *nightmare* to maintain.

To make this maintainable, IME you need a few things:

- A distinct and well-defined data-access layer, the API boundary of which looks after retrieving and storing persistent storage and very little else.

  I don't like to use the term "model" for that because that is contentious. Whatever calls that layer should not care how the data is stored, should not even be worrying about things like database handles: that is *all* the job of the data-access layer.
- A dispatcher that is very light and doesn't do any magic outside of just dispatching.

Now you can put everything else in one place that accepts requests and parameters, probably normalised and error checked from the dispatcher, fetches the data (usually as objects) it needs, makes the changes it needs to do, saves the data it needs to, hands the data is needs to display to the view. Two hundred lines of code plodding through the task *works* for this step. You don't need to hive off bits into functions in another file that are called from nowhere else. You can even put the view on the end of this file! Idealism is nice to aspire to but pragmatism needs a look-in because *this is maintainable*.

(Okay, rant over... )

PHP's lack of enforcing a framework means that the best frameworks do what PHP does: they stay out of the way. Some of the most maintainable code I've worked on had a single `require()` statement at the top, did all the data-manipulation with data objects (no SQL in sight), then output HTML surrounded by template functions, with form control being done by a consistent function API.